# React-native run-android is not working because it cant found any emulators macOS

Tags: android, react-native

I created react-native project and when I run `react-native run-ios` it is working perfectly.
But the problem is android.
Whenever I run `react-native run-android` it gives me this error:

```
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
```

After this error it begins to install the app and in the end I get this error.

```
   error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
```

I installed latest java and jdk tools.
I found some solutions on stack overflow and I followed one which suggested to clean Gradlew file in the android folder but it did not work either.

any suggestions please?

My OS is macOS Catalina

Comment: Did you install Android Studio and configured the Android emulator?

Comment: Yeap I already fixed this error it was issue with Gradlew version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone encounters this problem.
I solved it this way

***1.ANDROID STUDIO***

I went to the android studio and updated all the tools needed for the emulator

***2.Android folder inside the project***

I went to the android folder of my project, inside of ***android/app/gradle*** Gradle-wrapper file and updated `distributionUrl` to the latest version

***3.Clear cache***

I ran `npm --reset-cache start`

***4.Final step***

After all of this I opened android emulator and ran `react-native run-android` in my app and it worked